# Powershell command/script to find out all documents based on modified date time?

Tags: windows, powershell, directory, command

Im not familiar with powershell, I know dir command where you can find documents based on modified date(`forfiles /P directory /S /D +08/01/2013`).

But in powershell, is there a command to get all the documents with specified modified date? lets say to list all the documents which modified date on (02/05/2016)

I hope you can help me out with this. Thank you so much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to retrieve all files (`-Recurse`if needed). And use the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet to filter them based on your desired property:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "your_directory" -Recurse  | where {$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq ([datetime]::Parse('02/05/2016'))}
```